# How to get a folder of mp3's inside of my react application

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, react-dom

I have a folder of mp3's inside of the same directory as all my components. I want to be able to loop through these to dynamically render a audio element for each. The problem I ran into is it will not allow me to import the folder. When I use the path `./components/songs` (songs is the name of the folder with the songs) it says `./src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve './components/Songs' in '/Users/nathangriffith/Desktop/dashboard/src'` To try and combat this I wrote a script that spits out the correct path and title for each track and then sent that to a json data. My thinking was at least I could get the write src for each but that turned out to not to just literally give me the src for each but it doesn't recognize the song.

Here is my app.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TESTDATA from "./components/object.json";
import ReactAudioPlayer from "react-audio-player";
import useSimpleAudio from "use-simple-audio";
import Songs from "./components/Songs"
import { Howl, Howler } from "howler";
import ReactHowler from "react-howler";

const App = () => {
  const [sound, setSound] = useState(false);

  let click = e => {
    setSound(!sound);
  };
  console.log(TESTDATA.map(e => e));

  let check = TESTDATA.map(e => (
    <div>
      {e} <ReactAudioPlayer src={e} autoplay={false} controls />{" "}
    </div>
  ));

  return <div>{check}</div>;
};

export default App;
```

Here is the node.js script that writes each file location to a json file that I am using in App.js

```
const fs = require("fs");
const mm = require("music-metadata");
const dataFolder = "./Songs";
const util = require("util");
//requiring path and fs modules
const path = require("path");
let FileName = [];

fs.readdirSync(dataFolder).forEach(file => {
  return {
    song: FileName.push(`./Songs/${file}`)
  };
});

fs.writeFile("./object.json", JSON.stringify(FileName), err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("File has been created");
});

console.log(FileName);
```

Here is what is inside of the json file.

```
["./Songs/.DS_Store","./Songs/04 Playa.mp3","./Songs/1.mp3"]
```

Comment: I might be wrong here.  But isn't React a frontend framework?  A frontend language/framework will not be able to read from the filesystem.  You would need a serverside language like node, php, etc to do that.

Comment: Thats what I did with the songBringer.js or so I thought